# PyInstaller FileNotFound Error when "Appending archive to EXE"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I try to export my python .pyw file to a .exe file, PyInstaller manages to create the .exe file in the dist folder, which I have seen by looking in file explorer while PyInstaller is running

However, after the line "Appending archive to EXE D:\Code\Python\Plumber\dist\main.exe", this error comes up:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'D:\\Code\\Python\\Plumber\\dist\\main.exe'
```

Every time I have tried to compile this .pyw file to .exe, invcluding when I have removed, added, and changed arguments in the command, it comes up with this same error.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and what I can do to fix them?

Full error output:

```
17758 INFO: Appending archive to EXE D:\Code\Python\Plumber\dist\main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Code\Python\_lib\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 126, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 815, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 762, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "D:\Code\Python\Plumber\main.spec", line 23, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 524, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 159, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 782, in assemble
    set_exe_checksum(self.name)
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winutils.py", line 168, in set_exe_checksum
    pe = pefile.PE(exe_path)
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\site-packages\pefile.py", line 1841, in __init__
    self.__parse__(name, data, fast_load)
  File "d:\code\python\_lib\lib\site-packages\pefile.py", line 1884, in __parse__
    stat = os.stat(fname)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'D:\\Code\\Python\\Plumber\\dist\\main.exe'
```

Comment: how do you run `PyInstaller`?

Comment: It sounds like a Antivirus file removal. Check your antivirus logs.

Comment: Please share the full command you used and not just the output. Which version of python and pyinstaller are you using? Windows/Linux/mac?

Comment: The command I used to get this specific error message was PyInstaller --onefile main.pyw.  I am using a windows pc with PyInstaller 4.5.1 and Python 3.9.6

Comment: I fixed the issue, it was an antivirus file removal. Thank you gfdsweds for helping me work out what it was!